# How to override html for a module within custom theme?

Tags: magento2, html, braintree, custom-theme

What is the correct way to customize Braintree payment options - add image for payments card ? **How to override module-braintree HTML within my custom theme?**

I tried to copy form.html from

```
vendor/magento/module-braintree/view/frontend/web/template/payment/form.html
```

and customize it and paste to:

```
app/design/frontend/MJ/theme/Magento_Braintree/web/template/
```

Also tried here:

```
app/design/frontend/MJ/theme/Magento_Braintree/templates/html/
```

but the native one shows instead (I used different classes names to disgusting files). So I assume I have the wrong structure.

My goal was to add payment method images like Visa and PayPal to appear under Credit Card options. I managed to do so by editing this file:

```
vendor/magento/module-braintree/view/frontend/web/template/payment/form.html
```

Adding this code:

```
    <span class="field type">
        <span class="control">
            <ul class="credit-card-types amir-credit-card-types">
                <!-- ko foreach: {data: getCcAvailableTypes(), as: 'item'} -->
                <li class="item  item._active _active"  >
                    <!--ko if: $parent.getIcons(item) -->
                    <img class="" data-bind="attr: {
                            'src': $parent.getIcons(item).url,
                            'width': $parent.getIcons(item).width,
                            'height': $parent.getIcons(item).height
                        }">
                    <!--/ko-->
                </li>
                <!--/ko-->
            </ul>
        </span>
    </span>
```

And my objective was achieved:

[image]

Now my question is, how to override `module-braintree` within my custom theme?

I was not sure how to structure folders or where to place `form.html`This is what I tried:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The correct path is:

```
app/design/frontend/MJ/theme/Magento_Braintree/web/template/form.html
```

Delete all the other files and make sure you’ve deployed static content. Depending on the version of Magento 2 and your deployment mode, that might be what’s causing the issue.

Go to `pub/static/{your file path}` and check if the file exists. It will only work when the file exists at the above mentioned path.

**Update**

Copy

```
vendor/magento/module-braintree/view/frontend/web/template/payment/form.html
```

To

```
app/design/frontend/MJ/theme/Magento_Braintree/web/template/payment/form.html
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

Your answer inspired me dig further in pub/static/{theme} (as obvious as that step is, it never occurred to me) and by examining how Luma and Blank arranged their structure for the form of Braintree Module. It seems I was supposed to keep the original module structure and use it in my custom theme having **form.html** place in a dir called **payment**. 
The original **form.html** in **module-braintree** has the following path: 

**public_html/vendor/magento/module-braintree/view/frontend/web/template/payment/form.html**

Comment: Keyword in **/web/template/payment/form.html**

Full path should look like this: 

**/app/design/frontend/MJ/theme/Magento_Braintree/web/template/payment/form.html**

Comment: Since you already posted your answer, you could kindly edit it so I can select it as the answer of this question.